# htaccess mod_rewrite: order of rules to prevent index.php from showing up

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have three .htaccess rules:

1. one that checks if the domain doesn't start with www. and it prepends it to the hostname
2. one that checks if the host is called without using the https protocol, and it enforces it
3. last resort rule, if none of the above are matched, it will redirect to index.php/$0 where $0 is anything matched after the "/" in the URL:

This is how the file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Everything works file, but when there's no `https` and no `www` altogether, the user is redirected to  `https://` with `www.`, however `index.php` is also showing up.

e.g.

```
http://domain.com/test
```

...is being redirected to...

```
https://www.domain.com/index.php/test
```

instead of...

```
https://www.domain.com/test
```

What could be the problem?

Many thanks,
Vlad

Comment: hi, no, test is actually a CodeIgniter route pointing to index.php/controller/test

Comment: Is there any other .htaccess or any other rule in your system?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using a passthrough for the `index.php` rule... The [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt) states:

> The target (or substitution string) in a RewriteRule is assumed to be a file path, by default. The use of the [PT] flag causes it to be treated as a URI instead. That is to say, the use of the [PT] flag causes the result of the RewriteRule to be passed back through URL mapping, so that location-based mappings, such as Alias, Redirect, or ScriptAlias, for example, might have a chance to take effect.

As you are not using an `Alias`, `Redirect`, or `ScriptAlias`, `PT` does not apply to your rule-set.

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Alternatively, one of the following:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```